# Laravel Schema::getColumnListing not returing in a specific table

Tags: laravel

I'm using \Schema::getColumnListing to get all columns of a table. It works wonders in all tables except one.

This one table is up in the database, it's model it's working like a charm but when I call \Schema::getColumnListing it shows and empty array.

How can this be solved?

Answer (score 1):

```
DB::getSchemaBuilder()->getColumnListing('table');
```

Answer (score 0):

**table** is a reserved keyword and cannot be used.

Comment: See the Updated Answer

Answer (score 0):

That's because you're passing the wrong table name to the getColumnListing() method, that happened to me